# jQuery: Re-enabling disabled input buttons after 'success:' is run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following jQuery code in place to disable some form buttons if a specified condition is met. A PHP file is called to match the user's input to a database lookup. If the input matches the lookup, then the buttons are disabled and a message (uinError) is displayed. Here is the jQuery:

```
$(function() 
{
  $('input[id="empUIN"]').keyup(function(event) 
  {
      var uin = $('#empUIN').val();

      $.ajax(
      {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'uinlookup.php',
          data: 
          {
              term: uin
          },
          success: function(data) 
          {

              $('#uinError').html(data);
              $('#class1Buttons :input').attr('disabled', true);
          }
      }); //End ajax         

     event.preventDefault();

    }); 
 }); //End function
```

This works if there is a match, but I need to re-enable the buttons if the user provides input that does NOT trigger a match (i.e., if he backspaces over the input and types a new number). Right now, the buttons remain disabled no matter the input in empUIN.

Comment: Where is your condition? In the php file? What does it return when it does not match?

Comment: The condition is in uinlookup.php. It just returns 0 if the condition (user input == DB lookup) is not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.prop()` :

```
$('#class1Buttons :input').prop('disabled', true); //true = disabled, false = enabled. Not sure what you want
```

In your case, that should work :

```
$('#class1Buttons :input').prop('disabled', data);
```

Comment: Yep, the latter is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Return failed request in PHP (example of 500 status).

   ```
   header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
   header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
   die(json_encode(array('error' => true))); // some optional data returned
   ```
2. Add an error function to your jQuery call.

   ```
   $(function() 
   {
       $('input[id="empUIN"]').keyup(function(event) 
       {
           var uin = $('#empUIN').val();

       $.ajax(
       {
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'uinlookup.php',
           data: 
           {
               term: uin
           },
           success: function(data) 
           {
               $('#uinError').html(data);
               $('#class1Buttons :input').attr('disabled', true);
           },
           error: function()
           {
               // enable button
               $('#class1Buttons :input').attr('disabled', false);
           },
       }); //End ajax

       event.preventDefault();
       });
   }); //End function
   ```

You can read more about [jQuery.ajax() here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#class1Buttons :input").removeAttr('disabled')` to remove the attribute.