# Re-Enable Submit button after success in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to enable **Submit Button** after the AJAX Request success. The validation is in PHP file which has following code

```
    if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {

        $fetch = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE std_username='" . $_POST["username"] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $fetch);
        $user_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($user_count>0) {
            echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Username Not Available.</span>";
        }else{
            echo "<span class='status-available'> Username Available.</span>";
        }
    }
```

and this is **AJAX**

```
    function checkAvailability() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "check_availability.php",
        data:'username='+$("#username").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
    }
```

I have used this is **success** what it does is disable the submit button even the data matches the request or not, the button stays disabled

```
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
```

and following in **error**

```
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
```

I have gone throught these questions and tried the solutions but those solutions didn't work out for me.

[jQuery: Re-enabling disabled input buttons after 'success:' is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181717/jquery-re-enabling-disabled-input-buttons-after-success-is-run) **and**

[Disable Button while AJAX Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622499/disable-button-while-ajax-request)

this is the **HTML**

```
    <form method="POST">
        <label>Check Username:</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="demoInputBox" onBlur="checkAvailability()"><span id="user-availability-status"></span><br>    
        <label>Check Username:</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="demoInputBox" onBlur="checkAvailabilitye()"><span id="email-availability-status"></span> <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit"> 
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the success event, you need to set the `disabled` property value to false. This will re-enable the button

```
$( "#submit" ).prop( "disabled", true ); //disable when ajax call starts

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "check_availability.php",
    data:'username='+$("#username").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $( "#submit" ).prop( "disabled", false ); //enable it back
        $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
```

**EDIT : *As per the comments*,**

Looks like you are trying to enable/disable button based on the check you are doing aginist the db table. Currently your php script is returning a human readable string. May be you can change your php script to return a flag value which your javascript code can use.

```
if($user_count>0) {
        echo "no";
}else{
        echo "available";
}
```

And in your success handler inspect this value and hide/show buttons/messages

```
success:function(data){
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        var msg="Not available";

        if(data=="available")
        {
          $( "#submit" ).prop( "disabled", false ); //enable it back
          msg="Username available";
        }
        $("#user-availability-status").html(msg);

},
```

*I am not a PHP person. There could be a way to return JSON structure from your PHP page which can return both the flag and the message you want to show in the message div.  You may try that too.*

Comment: it looks like this now, is it correct?
success:function(data){
    $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
    $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    $( "#submit" ).prop( "disabled", false );
   },
   error:function (){}
   });

Comment: Yes. It should work if you do not have any other script errors in the page and you are hitting the success event from the ajax call.Check your browser console for script errors and put a `console.log('success occured')` inside the success handler to verify it

Comment: I have tried the above snippet but still it doesn't disable the button if entered username matches the one in DB and vice versa :(

Comment: I have put console.log('success occured') and turns out there aren't any errors, it works fine but button problem is still there :(

Comment: Your question was about re-enabling the submit button in the success handler. My answer has nothing to do with what your validation script does with db.

Comment: so is it a query problem?

Comment: Thank You So much! That worked for me. I am new to these things and I make dumb mistakes anyhow thank again man! Love!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad i could help :) Don't worry everyone learns from such dumb mistakes.:)

Comment: Another little question: I am using this to validate username, is there anyway I could mess up with this **data:'username='+$("#username").val(),** to check multiple data? 
or How can we use data to check multiple data? is it clear to you i don't know exact terms for these things

Answer (score 1):

Use on success this:

```
$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
```

instead of

```
$("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
```

To make the button enabled again, you need to completely remove the `disabled` attribute.